# Confirm if column in a pandas dataframe is in a sequential order starting by one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Imagine I have the following column on a dataframe:

```
df['Col1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

What would be the best way to confirm if this column is in a sequential order having their lowest value starting with 1? In the example above, I would expect it to return "True".

Comment: Should be swapped `5,6` ?

Comment: No, should be this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need first sorting values and test sequential by difference is equal `1` for all values and then test if first value is `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]})

out = (np.diff(df['Col1'].sort_values()) == 1).all() and (df['Col1'].iat[0] == 1)
print (out)
True
```

If need test first sorted value:

```
s = df['Col1'].sort_values()
out = (np.diff(s) == 1).all() and (s.iat[0] == 1)
print (out)
True
```

If difference of ordered values should be positive:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5]})

out = (np.diff(df['Col1'].sort_values()) > 0).all() and (df['Col1'].iat[0] == 1)
print (out)
True
```

Comment: Thanks! If False then it is sequential? Because the list may not be in order but still, if the numbers once in order are sequential then it should be considered sequential

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sets` operation:

```
>>> False if set(df['Col1']).difference(range(1, 7)) else True
True
```